# Connect-IPPSSession with CertificateThumbPrint cmdlet showing sign in popup

Tags: powershell, azure, exchange, azure-powershell

I've set an application to be used by a script, to login on exchange online on an unattended way, following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps).

But when I try to login with it, I got the following outcome, there is a login sign in popup that its not supposed to show:

[image]

Note, I've that certificate installed in the same machine where I am running this script:

[image]

The way that I've used to create that certificate is the one step 3, recommended way.

Anyone knows how can I avoid that sign in from showing up, and let it do in fact an unattended login?

Thank in advance!

UPDATE1:

Tried with the newest exchange command and worked, but through that I am not able to use SCC cmdlets:

[image]

Have also installed the must recent ExchangeOnlineManagement version,

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.5
```

but still being popup with Connect-IPPSession ...

UPDATE2:

From documentation I need to have at least Exchange Online PowerShell module version 2.0.6-Preview5 or later, but when I use Connect-IPPSSession with CertificateThumbPrint when I close that login popup, I receive an error message with 3.0.0 on command path error.

On my system I've the following versions:

[image]

But really don't know how to force 2.0.6-Preview5 or later, under v2 to be used, instead of 3.0.0 who is the current one, for this case.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit Nov 21 2022:** The current [pre-release version 3.0.1 of ExchangeOnlineManagement](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/3.0.1-Preview1) has a fix for this.

---

I had a look at the cmdlets of the ExchangeOnlineManagement module 3.0.0.

### The Problem

The `Connect-IPPSSession` cmdlet internally calls the `Connect-ExchangeOnline` cmdlet but removes the `-ConnectCertificateThumbprint` parameter in the internal call when run from Windows PowerShell.

These are lines 853 to 681 of `ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1`:

```perl
# Will not pass CertificateThumbprint for other system except Windows
if($IsWindows -eq $true)
{
   Connect-ExchangeOnline -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName.Value -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption -Credential $Credential.Value -BypassMailboxAnchoring:$BypassMailboxAnchoring -ShowBanner:$false -DelegatedOrganization $DelegatedOrganization -Certificate $Certificate.Value -CertificateFilePath $CertificateFilePath.Value -CertificatePassword $CertificatePassword.Value -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint.Value -AppId $AppId.Value -Organization $Organization.Value -Prefix $Prefix -CommandName $CommandName -FormatTypeName $FormatTypeName -UseRPSSession:$true
}
else
{
   Connect-ExchangeOnline -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri $AzureADAuthorizationEndpointUri -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName.Value -PSSessionOption $PSSessionOption -Credential $Credential.Value -BypassMailboxAnchoring:$BypassMailboxAnchoring -ShowBanner:$false -DelegatedOrganization $DelegatedOrganization -Certificate $Certificate.Value -CertificateFilePath $CertificateFilePath.Value -CertificatePassword $CertificatePassword.Value -AppId $AppId.Value -Organization $Organization.Value -Prefix $Prefix -CommandName $CommandName -FormatTypeName $FormatTypeName -UseRPSSession:$true
}
```

The problem here is, that the `$IsWindows` variable was introduced with PowerShell Core and is not present by default in Windows PowerShell. This means that under Windows PowerShell the condition `$IsWindows -eq $true` evaluates as `$false`.

### The Workaround

As a workaround in Windows PowerShell you can set the `$IsWindows` variable globally before calling `Connect-IPPSSession`:

```perl
$Global:IsWindows = $true   
Connect-IPPSSession -AppId '{App ID}' -CertificateThumbprint '{Certificate thumbprint}' -Organization '{Your Organization}.onmicrosoft.com'
```

I have successfully tested this on Windows PowerShell 5.1 with ExchangeOnlineManagement 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

So this was the only way that I managed to solve this:

```
Get-Command Install-Module
Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
```

Close the terminal and open a new one, and do:

```
Get-Command Install-Module
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.6-Preview7 -AllowPrerelease
Import-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.6
Connect-IPPSSession -CertificateThumbPrint "<certificatethumbprint>" -AppID "<AppID>" -Organization "foobar.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]